# Редирект на вьюху с деталями модели после ее сохранения

Tags: python, django

Собственно в чем вопрос, есть модель Lot, есть форма LotAddForm и оно все добавляется нормально, но после добавления объекта нужно редиректить на страницу с его деталями которая тоже есть, но что бы редиректить нужно знать  id лота, получить id во время отправки формы не получается ибо он еще не сохранен, получить авто инкремент из таблицы  средствами cursor тоже не получается

```
def get_next_auto_increment(mymodel):
    from django.db import connection
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute("SELECT Auto_increment FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_name='" + mymodel._meta.db_table +"'")
    row = cursor.fetchone()
    cursor.close()
    return row[0]
```

Один раз работает после добавления следующего лота возвращает тот же id хотя если прописывать прямо к базе запрос то выводит уже новое значение, а у нас остается такое же, если у нас изменить код и перезапустить сервер то тоже получаем новое значение, как быть подскажите, возможно это можно сделать менее костыльно.

Comment: Что вам мешает после сохранения объекта получить его id и сделать редирект?

Comment: Это как? Просто мы редиректим через success_url, подскажите пожалуйста как можно иначе, что бы работало так же?

Comment: Вы используете CreateView?

Comment: Да generic.CreateView

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В CreateView в методе get_success_url вам уже доступен созданный обьект `self.object`

```
class MyCreateView(CreateView):
    ...

    def get_success_url(self):
        # Вот в этом методе у вас доступен self.object.id
        return reverse('my_detail_url_name', kwargs={'id': self.object.id})
```

Comment: Он будет сам вызываться вместо success_url=""?

Comment: Да. Этот метод вызывается всегда, если форма оказалась валидной. В родительском классе этот метод занимается тем, что возвращает указанный вами success_url

Answer (score 2):

В модели можно определить метод:

```
def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('Lot-detail-url-name', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
```

Тогда он автоматически будет использоваться в `CreateView` и `UpdateView` для определения `success_url`